VSCode Interpreter path changes during debugging session
I've been at this for about 2 hour and can't figure it out...
The interpreter used for debugger is changing depenging on if I 'start' debugging, vs if I 'restart' debugging.
I am using a launch.json file that states the interpreter path as:
"python": "c:\Users\dusti\python\bams\company_dash\.venv\Scripts\python.exe"
When I 'start debugging' (which works fine), I see this interpreter printed to the terminal like so:
dusti@Dustin MINGW64 ~/python/bams/company_dash (staging)
$  c:\\Users\\dusti\\python\\bams\\company_dash\\.venv\\Scripts\\python.exe c:\\Users\\dusti\\.vscode\\extensions\\ms-python.debugpy-2024.4.0-win32-x64\\bundled\\libs\\debugpy\\adapter/../..\\debugpy\\launcher 60832 -- C:\\Users\\dusti\\python\\bams\\company_dash\\z_negating.py

However, if I hit a breakpoint and then click the 'restart' button (which always worked just fine in the past...) it shows this:
dusti@Dustin MINGW64 ~/python/bams/company_dash (staging)
$ nv\\Scripts\\python.exe c:\\Users\\dusti\\.vscode\\extensions\\ms-python.debugpy-2024.4.0-win32-x64\\bundled\\libs\\debugpy\\adapter/../..\\debugpy\\launcher 60850 -- C:\\Users\\dusti\\python\\bams\\company_dash\\z_negating.py 
bash: nv\Scripts\python.exe: No such file or directory

It then sits idle for about 10 seconds and then displays a message of: "Timed out waiting for launcher to connect"
As you can see, the interpreter path is no longer the one specified (but this only happens when 'restarting' the debugger, compared to when initialling starting it), and for the life of me, I cannot find where it got this path from...
I recently changed the launch.json type to "type": "debugpy" and I do have the Python Debugger extension installed, but the problem existed before these were updated.
Any help is GREATLY appreciated.
